# TwitterTimeline.HomeTimeline only returns my tweets

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterizer

Why does the console app below, which uses the [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net) .NET library, only print out *my* tweets? As I understand it from [Twitter's API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline) it should return tweets from the people I am following as well. The only thing I can think of is that it is something to do with using an access token I generated for my own account as described [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples), but I haven't been able to find anything that confirms that.

```
public class Program
{
    private const int ConsumerKey       = 0;
    private const int ConsumerSecret    = 1;
    private const int AccessToken       = 2;
    private const int AccessTokenSecret = 3;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens()
        {
            ConsumerKey       = args[ConsumerKey],
            ConsumerSecret    = args[ConsumerSecret],
            AccessToken       = args[AccessToken],
            AccessTokenSecret = args[AccessTokenSecret]
        };

        TwitterResponse<TwitterStatusCollection> response = TwitterTimeline.HomeTimeline(tokens);

        foreach (TwitterStatus status in response.ResponseObject)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(status.Text);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you don't have external tweets on your timeline?

Comment: I definitely do have external tweets on my timeline. I can also see them if I use this console: https://dev.twitter.com/console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. It should return the same data set that is displayed when you login to www.twitter.com.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that my code looks OK and I haven't done anything stupid. Your library looks awesome if I can get it to work - I haven't confirmed it yet, but I think the problem is with the twitter API itself anyway, rather than Twitterizer.

Comment: Everything was working fine - I am an idiot! I used a twitter account that only follows one person (me) to generate the access token, therefore it was correctly returning just my tweets.